# CiviVolunteer - Reports Not Appearing

Tags: civivolunteer

I don't use this option a lot so forgive me if I'm just forgetting how this works, but last I knew in CiviVolunteer if you wanted to generate a report of the hours logged, you'd go to Contact Reports -> New Report and doing Volunteer Report would be an option from there. (Could have sworn I did this ages ago and saved it as a report, but that doesn't seem to be showing up either.)

I'm wondering if a recent upgrade might have hosed the CiviVolunteer reports? I'm on CiviCRM 5.22.0 running on WordPress 5.3.2.

I checked the CiviCRM logs and the only thing I see in there that I'm wondering might be related is this message:
`Deprecated Path: There is a setting (generate_schema_and_data) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems`

Other than that functionality seems normal from what I can tell so I'm a bit flummoxed and would appreciate any ideas folks might have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case an upgrade to 5.22.1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the report template is enabled by navigation to Administer >> CiviReport >> ManageTemplates? If disabled than enable it, if not found than add one with values shown in below screenshot
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't see any volunteer-related templates in the Manage Templates list.

Comment: Just upgraded to CiviCRM 5.22.1 and the report is back now. Must have been a glitch with 5.22.0 specifically. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: i did updated my answer